# How to run a Query in Access for a 30,000 records in a table of 800,000 records?

Tags: ms-access

How to run a Query in Access for the first 30,000 records in a table of 800,000 records?

```
UPDATE Table1 SET TIME = TimeSerial(Left(TIME,2),Right(TIME,2),0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the first thing to remember is that records could be pulled in any order, so we probably want to `ORDER BY`, to ensure that the top 30,000 records are the same each time (or if you want the next 30,000 records, that you don't end up repeating yourself etc.) I assumed you have some sort of id, you can figure out what to order by yourself.

What you're looking for is

```
UPDATE (SELECT TOP 30000 * FROM Table1 ORDER BY Table1.id) AS a 
SET a.TIME = TimeSerial(Left(a.TIME,2),Right(a.TIME,2),0);
```

Comment: Thank You. What I am actually trying to do is change the format of the 800,000 records first and then run a query. So when I change the format of the 'TIME' Field in Design View from Currently: "Short Text with Length 4" to New: "Short Text with length 16" I am unable to save it due to error: There is not enough memory. The reason I am using the length as 16 is after inserting a semicolon to the time I have to combine it with a DATE field. Finally I am trying to change the Time to military hence convert the field to Date/Time with format mm/dd/yyyy HH:nn.

Comment: I am able to make these changes for 30,000 records but I wish to do it for all 800,000 records. I also have to only use Microsoft Access to do so.

Comment: I would highly suggest that you change the Time field to be an actual Date/Time field, and then use `Format()` for display purposes. You can update all rows with the code you have in your question.

Comment: If I am changing the Format in Design View from Short Text to Date/Time it says there isn't enough disk space or memory.

Comment: Ok you need a better computer, or create a new table with the desired characteristics, and then do `INSERT INTO ([put every column here]) table2 SELECT [put every column here] FROM table1;`

Comment: No problem that's what this site is for! Please accept my answer if you consider your question solved, you can always ask a new question when you have a new problem.

Comment: I am trying to set a field equal to the difference of another field in the same row - another field in a previous row. What would be the best approach to do this? I have set a unique identification key for each row.            What I am trying to do is:   If Member_ID (i+1)th row = Member_ID (i)th row and if Date (i+1)th row > Date (i)th row set Time_Between_Segment = DateDiff("n",[Date_Time_Out (i)],[Date_Time_In (i+1)]

Comment: @VijendraMane please ask a new question